# React Native View Overlay excluding the image portion

Tags: react-native

I have a screen on which I need to place a transparent round image , the position of the image could be dynamic, I need to render the dynamic view excluding the image with a black overlay colour, such that image and the screen contents below the image remains same... Kind of like when there is an app tutorial , only the required portion is highlighted and the remaining screen is dull.. 
How can I do it ?

Comment: this does sound a lot like the `<Modal />` component. have you try it?

Comment: Modal component will also blur the image and the screen below it..

Comment: An image or a visual example of what you would like would be more helpful.